# What Shiny UI input function to use to pass a value to the server function, while the 'input' is not visible in UI

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create a Shiny UI with a 'hidden' field with an ID value that will be together with a textInput() be passed to the server function. The hidden field should not be visible in the UI. What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: This would be clearer if you explained why you want to do that, I think. Why hiding a field and passing it to the server instead of directly taking this value in the server?

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent. You are absolutely right. I just tried to be get a consistent piece of code while handling the input. I have now put in a reactiveVal and use that instead. The 'hidden' input wouldn't change so not trigger anything and therefore input$ didn't sound right.